# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, routes, laravel-blade

I have a problem when I click edit button in the `edit.blade.php`. In update function the PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('phones','PhonesController@index');
Route::post('store','PhonesController@store');
Route::delete('destroy/{id}','PhonesController@destroy');
Route::put('edit/{id}', 'PhonesController@edit');
Route::post('update/{id}','PhonesController@update');
```

**View edit.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Edit {{$phone->name}}
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- Display Validation Errors -->
                <!-- New Task Form -->
            <form action="{{url('update/'.$phone->id)}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                        @csrf     


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
@method('put')
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**and Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $phone= Phone::find($id);

    return view('edit',compact('phone'));
}

public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:10',
        'model'=>'required'
    ]);

    $phone=new Phone();
    $phone->name=$request->input('name');
    $phone->model=$request->input('model');
    $phone->save();

    return back();
}
```

Just this is a problem I tried another ways but still getting same problem
thank you.

Comment: You don't have `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">` in your form anywhere, do you?

Comment: what edit button? there is nothing here that is sending a PUT request or a POST request with a spoofed `_method` as PUT, there is nothing here that can send a post request at all

Comment: i have  but i clip it because too muck code

Comment: edit your question with the information, dont add the code to the comments

Comment: you defined your 'update' route as POST, but you are sending a PUT request, as simple as that :-)

Comment: Remove this `@method('put')`

Comment: or define the route as a PUT route

Comment: still not working

Comment: this error appear The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

Comment: Use resource controllers and routes instead of mimic all it's routes. It will prevent errors like that.

Comment: You probably changed the definition for the wrong route

Comment: they have a redirect back to a PUT route it would seem like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit route shouldn't be `PUT`, it should be `GET`. You should then adjust your update route to be `PUT` if you want to submit it that way:

```
Route::get('edit/{id}', 'PhonesController@edit');
Route::put('update/{id}','PhonesController@update');
```

Then what ever is sending you to the edit page can just be a regular hyper link (`GET`) which will allow you to redirect to it as well.

Comment: not if you want to redirect to it ..so no, it isnt correct, it should be GET

Comment: when i press edit it/s redirect to edit page but when ii confirm edit here its a problem

Comment: your controller is doing a redirect "back" that would be the "edit" page, redirects are GET requests, so it has to be a GET route ...

Comment: ok i change it but still getting a problem The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

Comment: thanks it's working but still have error in edit.blade.php

Comment: no problem ... lots of moving parts involved with this stuff :-)